Symmetric algebraic relation of X(74)-centric system
Note a property of rectangular hyperbola: the orthocenter of any three points on the curve is still on the curve.
Take three points on the rectangular hyperbola $xy=1$, whose $x$-coordinates are $a, b, c $.
So the three points are $(a,\frac1a)$, $(b,\frac1b)$, $(c,\frac1c)$.
Intersecting the line $AH:y=-\frac{b-c}{\frac 1 b-\frac 1 c}(x-a)+\frac1a$ with $BH:y=-\frac{c-a}{\frac 1 c-\frac 1 a}(x-b)+\frac1b$, we get the orthocenter $H$ of $\triangle ABC$ is the point $(-\frac1{abc},-abc)$.
So we parametrized the rectangular hyperbola by $x$-coordinate, and deduced 4 points on the curve $(a,\frac1a)$, $(b,\frac1b)$, $(c,\frac1c)$, $(d,\frac1d)$ form an orthocentric system if and only iff $abcd=-1$.
Note this relation is symmetric in $a,b,c,d$, so the orthocentric system remains an orthocentric system under permutation of the four points.

X(74) is the isogonal conjugate of infinity point of Euler line.
In Hyacinthos 8129 (10/4/03), Floor van Lamoen noted that if $X(74)$ is denoted by $J$, then each of the points $A,B,C,J$ is $J$ of the other three, in analogy with the well known property of orthocentric systems (that is, each of the points $A,B,C,H$ is the orthocenter of the other three).

In analogy with the property of rectangular hyperbola, note that the $X(74)$ of any three points on a circle is still on a circle.
In analogy with the orthocentric system, note that the $X(74)$-system remains an $X(74)$-system under permutation of the four points, so I wish to find a symmetric relation for 4 points on the unit circle to form an $X(74)$-centric system.
We can parametrize the unit circle by angle, and let $(\cos(2α),\sin(2α))$, $(\cos(2β),\sin(2β))$, $(\cos(2γ),\sin(2γ))$, $(\cos(2δ),\sin(2δ))$ be 4 points on the unit circle.
My question is: How to prove that they form an X(74)-centric system if and only iff $\cos(α-β+γ-δ)+\cos(α-β-γ+δ)+\cos(α+β-γ-δ)=0$?
Note that this relation is symmetric in $α,β,γ,δ$, and is invariant under rotation/reflection symmetry of the unit circle.
GeoGebra link


To prove that the points $(\cos(2\alpha), \sin(2\alpha))$, $(\cos(2\beta), \sin(2\beta))$, $(\cos(2\gamma), \sin(2\gamma))$, and $(\cos(2\delta), \sin(2\delta))$ form a X(74)-centric system if and only if $\cos(\alpha - \beta + \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta - \gamma + \delta) + \cos(\alpha + \beta - \gamma - \delta) = 0$, I use complex coordinates.
Let $A(a), B(b), C(c)$, and $D(d)$ be four points on the unit circle. The orthocenter $H$ of triangle $ABC$ has coordinate $a + b + c$ because $\mathbf{OH} = \mathbf{OA} + \mathbf{OB} + \mathbf{OC}$, where $O$ is the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$, which coincides with the origin due to our choice of coordinatization. The reflections of $D$ across $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ have coordinates:
$$
  d - \frac{(d - b)(d - c)}{d}, d - \frac{(d - c)(d - a)}{d}, d - \frac{(d - a)(d - b)}{d}
$$
$d$ is X110 if and only if $O, H$, and the reflections of $D$ across $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ are collinear.
$O(0)$, $H(a + b + c)$ and the reflection of $D$ across $BC$ are collinear if and only if
$$
 \det\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & d - \frac{(d - b)(d - c)}{d} & a + b + c \\
   0 & 1/d - \frac{(1/d - 1/b)(1/d - 1/c)}{1/d} & 1/a + 1/b + 1/c
  \end{pmatrix} = 0
$$
which is equivalent to $(ad+bc)(-ab-ac-bc+ad+bd+cd) = 0$. Similarly, $O, H$ and the reflection of $D$ across $CA$ are collinear if and only if $(bd+ca)(-ab-ac-bc+ad+bd+cd) = 0$; $O, H$ and the reflection of $D$ across $AB$ are collinear if and only if $(cd+ab)(-ab-ac-bc+ad+bd+cd) = 0$.
If $d = \frac{ab + bc + ca}{a + b + c}$ then everything is satisfied. Otherwise, $d \ne \frac{ab + bc + ca}{a + b + c}$ then $d = \frac{-bc}{a} = \frac{-ca}{b} = \frac{-ab}{c}$, from which we deduce that $a^{2} = b^{2} = c^{2}$, which means there are two identical complex numbers in $a, b, c$. Hence $D$ is X(110) if and only if $d = \frac{bc + ca + ab}{a + b + c}$. Because X(74) is the antipode of X(110) in the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$, $D$ is X(74) if and only if $d = -\frac{bc + ca + ab}{a + b + c}$. Equivalently, $D$ is X(74) if and only if $ab + bc + ca + ad + bd + cd = 0$.
Now let $a = \exp(\iota 2\alpha), b = \exp(\iota 2\beta), c = \exp(\iota 2\gamma), d = \exp(\iota 2\delta)$. Using Euler's formula and some trigonometric identities, we obtain
\begin{align*}
 & ab + bc + ca + ad + bd + cd = 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \exp(\iota (2\alpha + 2\beta)) + \exp(\iota(2\beta + 2\gamma)) + \exp(\iota(2\gamma + 2\alpha)) + \exp(\iota (2\alpha + 2\delta)) + \exp(\iota (2\beta + 2\delta)) + \exp(\iota (2\gamma + 2\delta)) = 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \begin{cases}
    \cos(2\alpha + 2\beta) + \cos(2\beta + 2\gamma) + \cos(2\gamma + 2\alpha) + \cos(2\alpha + 2\delta) + \cos(2\beta + 2\delta) + \cos(2\gamma + 2\delta) = 0 \\
    \sin(2\alpha + 2\beta) + \sin(2\beta + 2\gamma) + \sin(2\gamma + 2\alpha) + \sin(2\alpha + 2\delta) + \sin(2\beta + 2\delta) + \sin(2\gamma + 2\delta) = 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \begin{cases}
2\cos(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta) \times (\cos(\alpha + \beta - \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta + \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta - \gamma + \delta)) = 0 \\
2\sin(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)\times (\cos(\alpha + \beta - \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta + \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta - \gamma + \delta)) = 0
\end{cases} \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \cos(\alpha + \beta - \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta + \gamma - \delta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta - \gamma + \delta) = 0
\end{align*}
The last line is true because $\cos(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)$ and $\sin(\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)$ cannot be zero simultaneously.
